# Execute code in red hat 4

Tags: linux, matlab, environment-modules

I have an ec2 instance in  redhat 4.

```
Linux version 4.4.41-36.55.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-60008) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jan 18 01:03:26 UTC 2017
```

I'm trying to execute a code made in matlab 2015b I have the m file.

So first I installed the MCR with unziping mat and executing ./install and later I add the environment variables :

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/sys/os/glnxa64:

MATLAB=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90
```

to my bashrc

So next I wanted to do is execute the m file but in `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v90/bin` there is no matlab script.

Reading a little what I need to do is this post: https://hpc.nih.gov/apps/Matlab_compiler.html but When I tried to execute : `module load matlab/v90` says module commantd not found

I try this: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/59399/module-command-not-found-in-fedora-21/ Adding ". /etc/profile" to my `.bashrc` but seems not to work.

So three questions

How can I run this file .m file, what are the steps for 2015b in
linux 64 bit?
How to get `module` command working on redhat 4?
For the question 2, I have `insmod` and `modprobe` in `/sbin/` folder...
are this related to add matlab?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't execute the `m` file, when only `MCR` is installed (not in Linux, Windows or MAC). The`MCR` contains only the shared objects dependent by executable code. First, you need to compile the `m` file to executable code (need full Matlab installation with Matlab compiler toolbox license). Then you can execute it like other executable in Linux.

Comment: What else shoul I install?

Comment: For getting it working on linux?

Comment: In some cases you can execute an `m` file using [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). Or install Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

`module` command here refers to the [Environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net) software and not the Linux kernel modules. You should be able to install `module` on your system by following the [installation documentation provided](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/INSTALL.html).